# I am confusing, help please

Tags: articles

Which one is correct?
1. Peter hasn't been to the bank yet.
2. Peter hasn't been to a bank yet.
3. Peter Hasn't been to bank yet.

Comment: 3 isn't correct.

Comment: @HotLicks  not if *to bank* is a verb

Comment: @Clare - Would not be idiomatic in the US.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both 1 and 2 are acceptable sentences:
"A" and "the" fall under the word class of determiners. "A" is an indefinite article, referring to an unspecified bank (in this case). In "Peter hasn't been to the bank yet", the bank being referred to is an unspecified one- it could be any bank!

One the other hand, "the" is a definite article. It refers to a specific bank- so Peter visited a specific bank that the speaker had in mind when crafting that sentence.

Also, bear in mind that confusing=/=confused. The correct question to ask would be "I am confused, please help!"